# Daily occupancy query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: one with the permits(id_permit, id_instalation, boat_license, boat_arrival_date, boat_exit_date) and one with the instalations(id_instalation, instalation_capacity), and I need to show the dates where the capacity is not full and the mean usage between those dates, separated by instalation id.
I´m trying using this:

```
select (generate_series('2018-06-29', '2018-07-03', '1 day'::interval))::date as date, permits.id_instalation, COUNT(permits.id_permit) 
FROM permits, 
     instalations 
WHERE permits.id_instalation = instalations.id_instalation 
  AND permits.arriva_date BETWEEN '2018-06-29' AND '2018-07-03' 
GROUP BY date, permits.id_instalation;
```

I think my trouble is that I´m not iterating through dates.

The data i have is from two diffetrent csv files:
This is the one with installations, where the columns are id, type, capacity, port name, city name, region name, boss id

[installations.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xrlf.png)

This is the one with the permits, where the columns are id permit, id instalation, ship name, ship license, country, arrival date, exit date, activity description

[permits.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xORzA.png)

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code in the form of a [mre], and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: sorry it's my first time posting here

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages. :-)

Comment: Now I've updated with the code I'm trying to use.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You need an outer join between the list of dates and the permits/installations tables. But that can't be done using the ancient implicit joins you are using, only with an explicit `left join` operator. You also need to put `generate_series()` into the `from` clause:

```
SELECT g.dt::date, p.id_instalation, COUNT(p.id_permit) 
FROM generate_series('2018-06-29', '2018-07-03', '1 day'::interval) as g(dt)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pm.id_instalation, pm.arriva_date, pm.id_permit
    FROM permits pm
       JOIN instalations i ON pm.id_instalation = i.id_instalation 
  ) p ON p.arriva_date = g.dt::date
GROUP BY g.dt::date, p.id_instalation
ORDER BY g.dt::date;
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm reciebing an error: "subquery in FROM must have an alias. LINE 3: LEFT JOIN (. HINT: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.". And I tried to use an alias but it didn't work. Also, with p, you are referring to permits table?

Comment: @VICENTETUNONVENDER: I fixed the missing alias

Comment: It worked, but it's showing me a table without any id_instalation, maybe it's because an instalation can have many permits?